# MySQL GREATEST() not working in ORDER BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

In the following query I am experiencing a problem. The `GREATEST()` function is not working here in the `ORDER BY` clause. I want to sort the results based on the two timestamps from two different tables inside the `GREATEST()` function. It's not giving the relative result according to the most recent date. What is wrong here? Am I missing something?

```
SELECT R1.swp_to, R1.swp_type, R1.swp_date, M.mem_fname, M.mem_lname, M.mem_last_activity, DP.dp_photo, GREATEST(R1.swp_date, R2.swp_date) FROM swipes AS R1
INNER JOIN swipes AS R2 ON(R1.swp_to = R2.swp_by AND R2.swp_to = R1.swp_by AND R2.swp_type <> 'left')
LEFT JOIN members AS M ON(R1.swp_to = M.mem_id)
LEFT JOIN display_photos AS DP ON(R1.swp_to = DP.dp_mem AND DP.dp_index = 1)
LEFT JOIN messages AS MSG ON((R1.swp_to = MSG.msg_from AND R1.swp_to = MSG.msg_to) OR (R1.swp_by = MSG.msg_from AND R1.swp_by = MSG.msg_to))
WHERE R1.swp_by = :mem AND R2.swp_by IS NOT NULL AND R1.swp_type <> 'left'
ORDER BY GREATEST(MSG.msg_time, R1.swp_date) DESC
```

I have attached a fiddle below with all my tables and data in above query.

Fiddle Here: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f6157/1)

Comment: @forpas please check again. I have updated the data but still no use. Record with id 11 should be on top as the `MSG.msg_time` as the most recent date now.

Comment: `GREATEST()` returns NULL if either of the parameters is NULL. MSG.msg_time is NULL that's why

Comment: @CodeWithDesire MSG.msg_time is still null with your new data: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5ruFY4qSzp1CbztETmAcvp/1

Comment: It seems that the LEFT joins in your code do not match to the table MSG so the column msg_time  is null.

Comment: @forpas but why is it showing null when data is present in the table? Can you help correct my query??

Comment: This quite complicated condition: `LEFT JOIN messages AS MSG ON((R1.swp_to = MSG.msg_from AND R1.swp_to = MSG.msg_to) OR (R1.swp_by = MSG.msg_from AND R1.swp_by = MSG.msg_to))` seems that does not match any row of the table `messages`. Check the condition again against your data.

Comment: Is it possible for `R1.swp_to` to be equal to `MSG.msg_from` and `MSG.msg_to` at the same time? Or `R1.swp_by` to be equal to `MSG.msg_from` and `MSG.msg_to` at the same time? I don't think so.

Comment: @forpas you are a genius.. i was about to add this problem to the question as well asking if my join statement for messages table is correct or not according to the given data and required output. But I didn't ask bcoz at the last moment I thought it's correct. But as it's returning null, please help me rectify the query as I find it correct and can't reach another solution. However, since you have too mentioned the same on top of my doubt, I feel that it's this join that's messing up. If it's corrected things will be sorted. Please help.

Comment: I don't know what you want to do. This is a 5 table join query. You join R1 to messages. What is the correct condition? You are the only one who knows that.

Comment: msg_from and msg_to are message sender and receiver. Whereas, swp_by and swp_to are users swiping each other for a match. So, if I consider user id 1, he can be either in swp_by or swp_to. Also, once matched, he can also be either a sender or a receiver to the message. So I had to meet all the conditions to join both the table. If you think it's incorrect, please suggest a correct join statement.

Comment: Post your expected results in tabular text format.

Comment: @forpas I tried creating a tabular format but I think this will be better. Let me try to explain with an example. If you still can't figure out then let me know at the end I will try to create a tabular example. So let's take the example of Tinder or Tantan that everybody used. In their messages section what happens is that whenever there is a new match, the message box list gets updated with a new record on top with a new match saying "It's a new match", tap on it and you can chat. If you receive a new message from another user later, it gets sorted on the top of the list... (next comment)

Comment: @forpas ...(continuing last comment) Any new message from any user gets sorted on top of the list as it being the latest one then any new match gets sorted on top of the list too if it is the most recent one to occur. We all understand how this works right? I want to achieve the exact same thing. Matches here are sorted from the `swipes` table and messages from the `messages` table. Both tables has a timestamp. Now whichever occourence is the first or say the most recent one according to the timestamp should be brought to the top of the list. That's the only thing I want to achieve. Plz help.

Answer (score 0):

The data available in your exmaple does not respond to the LEFT Joins with the messages table ,exactly `R1.swp_to = MSG.msg_t` and `R1.swp_to = MSG.msg_from`

```
LEFT JOIN messages AS MSG ON
((R1.swp_to = MSG.msg_from AND R1.swp_to = MSG.msg_to) 
OR (R1.swp_by = MSG.msg_from AND R1.swp_by = MSG.msg_to))
```

you can find [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c92e2/1/0) a modified example for your data

Comment: The example you gave there is nothing modified.. It's same as my query.. please check.

Comment: the same query but not the same data ! the probléme is with your data !

Comment: see my latest new comments to @forpas above and please see if you can help. I have explained what I actually want to do.